# GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl: getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

I am using firebase auth to my app and when I launch the app on android device I get error. What seems to be the problem and how to solve it?

```
[GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cclog
```

yej: Long live credential not available.

at jiy.a(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):8)
at jjd.g(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):1)
at jjd.e(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):3)
at jhl.m(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):108)
at fdh.m(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):31)
at fdh.e(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):66)
at fdh.h(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):0)
at jdi.a(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):3)
at jdp.t(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):4)
at jdp.s(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):10)
at jdg.p(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):4)
at xog.b(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):8)
at com.google.android.gms.clearcut.uploader.QosUploaderChimeraService.g(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):103)
at com.google.android.gms.clearcut.uploader.QosUploaderChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):2)
at apkd.call(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):4)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at zeu.c(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):6)
at zeu.run(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):7)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at zjz.run(:com.google.android.gms@222615028@22.26.15 (100400-461192076):0)